# excel procedure changes date format from English UK to American

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem with one of my procedures.
The procedure shifts data from one sheet to another and works fine however when moving date it changes the format from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY (01/04/2023 Becomes 04/01/2023)

```
  Sheet1.Range("N" & lRow).Value = Sheet4.Cells(17, 50) 'Date Required
```

All cells involved are set to the same Date format and after the transfer of the values the formatting hasn't changed when its been checked? Any ideas or pointers would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Do your cells actually contain dates? Setting the date format alone [is not enough](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365).

Comment: Try looking to **Dates where the month number is bigger than 12**. Are them shown correctly, except the format you are talking about? It is a matter of understanding the original data range format. I mean, if it is formatted as text, Excel guesses that it is about a `Date` cell and converts it, **but according to local regional settings**. In case of months bigger than 12 it cannot make the conversion and they will remain formatted as text... The problem can be solved, but only after you understand how the range in discussion was originally formatted and according to that, in different ways...